# Angular Project Arcitectural Design

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm new to Angular and MVC. My "Learn Angular" project is client for a home automation system. The system's server supports plug-ins (written in Python--something else to learn :-))

I have built the client with a responsive design (Bootstrap) and can get a list of all devices and their values using their RESTAPi (I'm using $http), so I'm reasonably comfortably with Angular basics now

Now I want to add functionality that will update the clients on a device statues change. (I don't want to do use polling) The plug-in architecture lets me create a plug-in that registers for changes in device states.

So here's my scenario:

- I have 5 touch screen (mix of Android and iOS) around the house. All will be running my client
  Let's assume they all have the lighting page shown, which has the
  status of all lights (on/off/dim level).
- Someone changes the living room light from 70% to 30%. This could be done by one of the clients, the native app on server or the light switch itself.
- The device status on the server will change and generate a notification that my plug-in will receive
- I need to update the state of the living room light on all 5 clients to show the living room light is now 30%

Not sure how I'd go about this. I'd like to do the minimum possible in Python and have no objections to using something like Node to send the notifications of that helps.

So I'm looking for suggestions on how to send this devices status change to all 5 clients (without a page refresh or polling). Can anyone help with some suggestions?

Regards

Mark

Comment: Have a look at socket.io

Comment: Have you thought about SignalR or something similar?